# Set multiple custom parameters for UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

```
.... Call to webservice
     NSArray *someValues = [results valueForKey:@"someKey"];
    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [someValues objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} // end

-(void)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    button.currentTitle; // Title comes back just fine
}
```

---

```
I want to be able to add more parameters so I can get them back on the click method. So example
button.someParam = @"My name"
...
// once clicked
UIButton *button = sender;
button.someParam // gets back "My Name"
```

Currently I can set a custom title and get it back just fine. I would like to add more values to pass along with my button. Is this possible? These values are coming back dynamically. I know I can set the tag # but that won't help me get custom values back from what I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add properties to a `UIButton`.

One way to do this is to make a `UIButton` subclass and add the properties there. Then use that subclass instead of a regular `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with sort of a hack fix for now. I'll keep on looking for the best way to implement this. But for now I just used the accessibilityValue as a parameter and then I was able to retrieve later.

```
    button.accessibilityValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [someArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: People making use of the accessibility features of their iOS device are going to be very confused when they use your app. Please do not do this.